# Is there actually a way to bind Checked event of a radio button to a command in the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, command, windows-10

I tried with

```
<RadioButton Content="Boom" Command={Binding MyCommand} IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"/>
```

but nothing happens. Why is that and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Add `System.Windows.Interactivity` reference

Step 2: Add Namespace in XAML `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"`

Step 3:

```
<RadioButton Content="Boom" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</RadioButton>
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to load hardware settings (lots of relays on/off, I/O ports etc.) to a ViewModels properties. Depending on the settings the concerned radios could be set. But, behind each radio there is a command doing something on the hardware, which would only be executed in case the radio was clicked by user, but not when set by change of the binded property. There are lots of answers to this, but yours is the shortest and best understandable way to solve it. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

The following code works as expected:

```
<RadioButton Content="Boom" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
```

That is, as in case of a regular `Button`, `MyCommand` is fired every time you click a `RadioButton`. If you're using `RadioButtons`, this, understandably, may not be what you want.

More useful will be passing some sort of data as a `CommandParameter` to know which option was checked:

```
<RadioButton Content="AAA" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="AAA" GroupName="MyGroup"/>
<RadioButton Content="BBB" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="BBB"  GroupName="MyGroup"/>
```

Example command method:

```
    private ICommand _MyCommand;
    public ICommand MyCommand
    {
        get { return _MyCommand ?? (_MyCommand = new DelegateCommand(a => MyCommandMethod(a))); }
    }

    private void MyCommandMethod(object item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Chosen element: " + (string)item);
    }
```